# adding prefix tel: to phone number variable from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, tel

How I can add prefix tel:*65* to my phone number, that I fetched from address book in array.

If I do this in viewdidload it's getting null

```
NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumbers]];
    NSLog(@"Some Text %@", phoneUrl);
    NSLog(@"Phone Numbers %@", phoneNumbers);
```

Here phoneNumbers is array with numbers per each contact

Udate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.jpg"]]];
    [detailTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    detailTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    ShadowTable *Shadow = [[ShadowTable alloc] init];
    [Shadow ForTableView:detailTableView ForView:self.view HeaderAlpha:0.3 FooterAlpha:0.6];

    for(int i = 0 ; i <[phoneNumbers count]; i++)
    {
        NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", [phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:i]]];
        NSLog(@"Phone with URL %@", phoneUrl);
        NSLog(@"Phone Numbers %@", phoneNumbers);
    }


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [phoneTypes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *typeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 40)];
    typeLabel.text = [phoneTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [typeLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell addSubview:typeLabel];



    UILabel *numberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 10, 170, 40)];
    numberLabel.text = [phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [numberLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell addSubview:numberLabel];

    if (indexPath.row %2 == 0) {

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1.0];
    } else {

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = [phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: post what is printed. Also try to print [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumbers]

Comment: if you are trying load it in a webView you have to select detect phone numbers. It will automatically detect.

Comment: you want to add "tel:" prefix to each element in the array?

Comment: And if phonenumbers is an array you are not making proper string. you got iterate the array to add tel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an array not a string. So you need to access all elements of array to add as suffix.

Use this :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <[phoneNumbers count]; i++)
{
    NSString *str = [@"tel:" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSLog(@"Some Text %@", phoneUrl);
}
```

**EDIT :** Url was null because there were spaces in "2013-05-31 14:58:24.759 GTCallBack[8225:c07]" so encode it to remove spaces.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, but phoneNumbers show ok and phoneUrl still null. I'll Update with a code my question

Comment: it seems like this 2013-05-31 14:58:24.758 GTCallBack[8225:c07] Phone with URL (null)
2013-05-31 14:58:24.759 GTCallBack[8225:c07] Phone Numbers (
    "(058) 758 0000"
)

Comment: Can you print your array. So that I could know the format of your array.

Comment: it's printed: 2013-05-31 14:58:24.759 GTCallBack[8225:c07] Phone Numbers (
    "(058) 758 0000"
) in this contact only one phone.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Url was null because there were spaces in "2013-05-31 14:58:24.759 GTCallBack[8225:c07]" so encode it. It will work

Comment: Thank you, just thought about the same thing :)